# Need to pass TestNG SuiteName to Jenkins Parameter, so that i can use it in post build actions to send html report as email

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, testng

I am using parametrized jobs to run Selenium suites in Jenkins, I am generating custom html report in `test-output\suiteName` to differentiate all the jobs report which are running parallelly and creating reports one after one.
Now, My problem is how to access html report with dynamic suitename path. i.e. "**test-output\${suiteName}\report.html**".
i have set-up a parameter as suiteName but how to set the suiteName from listener.

if any other solutions to solve this situation are also appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough details to imagine your case, but I try to help how I feel this might be implemented.

1. You have a Jenkins parameter `suiteName`.
2. You pass this parameter via run test command. E.g. if you're using maven:

   ```
    mvn clean test -DsuiteName=${suiteName}
   ```
3. In your test project

   > I am generating custom html report

   3.1. You already have some code, which generates the report. This is a custom TestNG Listener implementation (you've mentioned).

   3.2. And in the listener, you have some variable, which defines the html report output.

   3.3 And this variable populated from environment variable you're passing in test-run command.

   ```java
   public class CustomHtmlReportGenerator implements <some testNG listener interface {

       public static final String OUTPUT_PATH = "test-output\" + System.getProperty("suiteName") + "\report.html";

       // reporter implementation

       public void saveReportToFile() {
           // OUTPUT_PATH used here
       }

   }
   ```

So, for this implementation:

```
   ${suiteName} defined as Jenkins Job Parameter ->

             ${suiteName} passed to command line ->

                       ${suiteName} used in runtime by Custom TestNG Listener
```

> but how to set the suiteName from listener

This question still unclear for me, but I hope my explanations can help you to get what you want.